# When trying to interact with an element on the page, I get an error (javascript error: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null ')

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenide

I want to check if there is text in a frame using the Selenide library. But when I try to interact with the element, I get the error (javascript error: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null ')

My code looks like this:

In the first method is to open the letter and switch to the frame:

```
public Mailinator openLetter(int numberLetter) {
        letter(numberLetter).shouldBe(appear);
        letter(numberLetter).click();
        switchTo().frame("msg_body");
        return this;
    }
```

In the second method I am trying to validate the text.

```
public Mailinator checkRegularDeliveryPriceInEmail(String regularDeliveryPrice) {
        regularDeliveryPriceInEmail().shouldHave(text(regularDeliveryPrice));
        return this;
    }
```

And after that I get the error.
In the DOM html I do not find nested frames or any other frames, it is one.
Tell me, can someone come across this problem

The screenshot highlighted the element that I need to check for the content of the text (165,00)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC6vv.png)

Comment: Impossible to help you without more code. Since the element you want to access is null, i would assume it's not found by the `.frame()` method, so probably the `"msg_body"` string is the wrong parameter.

Comment: <iframe id="msg_body" style="border: 0;overflow: hidden;" title="Email Message Body" width="100%" height="1203" name="msg_body" marginheight="0">
                    EMAIL BODY
                </iframe>


msg_body - its frame id

Comment: <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 3px; text-align: right;">
                                            165,00&nbsp;<b>€</b>                                        </p>



And this is the element itself in which I need to check for the presence of text 165,00

This element is in an iframe

Comment: Added HTML screenshot

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("msg_body"); should work.

Comment: Hi @ЖораАвтоматизатор
Did you get the solution of your problem?

Comment: Hi @TomMartin no problem solved, it is not possible to switch to fraim

Comment: @arundeepchohan unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @ЖораАвтоматизатор
i have an idea, please switch from mailinator to faker email , in this no frames and easy to get the content via xpath.
Its suggestion only and up to you to use  or not.